# sql relation using with/without pivot to display dynamic columns

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table structure like below:

Table name: **questionsTable** and the date is look like

```
 qid      qName
  1        Enter your licence number.
  2        What is your favaorite sport.
  3        Enter your attendee name
```

Another Table name: **tbl_Answer** and the data is look like

```
qid    attendeeid    Answer
 1       2349         45645645
 2       2349         Cricket
 3       2350         James
 2       2350         Chess
 1       2350         858585
```

Now I want to display my output to look like this:

```
attendeeid   questionlable            answer     questionlable                 answer    questionlable          answer     
  2349        Enteryourlicencenumber  45645645   Whatisyourfavaoritesport      Cricket
  2350        Enteryourlicencenumber  858585     What is your favaorite sport  hockey   Enteryourattendeename  James
```

Here I want to display question lable dynamic because here sample I have taken 3 qid.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't have anything (as far as I know) that can pivot to a dynamic number of columns.

Additionally, you'll find that you need different names for the different columns, and so there would need to be a mechanism for dynamically naming columns.

The closest you may be able to get is to write some SQL that writes SQL and then execute that.  I certainly wouldn't want to go that route.

A better approach, in my opinion, is to pivot the data in your client.  As a general principle, I try to not deal with formating/layout/presentation issues on the SQL Server.  I find that it is better to simply ensure that the results provided give complete, accurate and consistent information, so as to enable the application to do what it wants.

(This enables your SQL to be about data in a way that is agnostic as to it's use.  This means that changes to the application are much less likely to require changes to the SQL.)